# Session data are lost using express session

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, express-session

I'm working in devMode with angularjs and express-session with cors middleware and I run frontend from localhost:4200 and backend from localhost:8080

In login request I set user data in session and then when I call "/api/contacts", the session user data is undefined.
I tried to save session with session.save() but it does not work.
I noticed that between calls sessionID changes.

I searched for hours on google but I have not found any solution.

this is the frontend call to "/api/contacts"

```
this.http.get(environment.apiUrl +    '/api/contacts', {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
```

this is part of server.js

```
app.use(cors({origin: [
  "http://localhost:4200"
], credentials: true,
}));

let sess = session({
  secret: 'my secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 60000 * 5 // prune expired entries every 24h
  }),
  cookie: { 
    secure: app.get('env') === 'production'?true:false,
    maxAge: 60000 * 5 ,

  }
})

app.use(sess)

// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
});

const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    // here req.session.user IS undefined
    if(req.session && req.session.user) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(403).send({
        status: 403,
        errorMessage: 'You must be logged in.'
      });
    }
};



app.get("/api/contacts",  authMiddleware,(req, res) => {
    // some code will run if authMiddleware pass
});





app.post('/api/login', validatePayloadMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.username === "xx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx" && req.body.password === "xxxxxxx")
  {

    let user = {
      id: req.sessionID,
      username: req.body.username,
      firstName: "Fabio",
      lastName: "Spadaro",
    };
    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.save((err) => {
      console.log(err) 
     });

    return res.status(200).json(user);
  }
  else
  {
    let body = {
          error: true,
          errorMessage: 'Permission denied!'
    };
    return res.status(403).json(body);
  }
});
```